# How to find a, b so that left of the linear plane is checked in the anti-clokwise way?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

I have the following problem and don't seem to find a solution (if it exists). I generate a linear plane (mx+k) and want to check if some point c is on the left of that plane. This can be done by the following cross product [solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line).

((b.X - a.X)*(c.Y - a.Y) - (b.Y - a.Y)*(c.X - a.X)) > 0

where b, a are points on the linear plane and c is the point to check against. However, depending where a, b points are on the linear plane are, two different answers can be obtained.

So, am trying to find such a, b that "left" would always be checked with the "anti-clockwise" direction of the planes (as shown in the image below)? If one selects point a at some random point on the plane, can it be determined where b point should be?

Thank you very much!
[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClNnH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Following the example image provided by the OP, instead of dealing with an algebraic equation of a line, use its vector equation which is

$ p(t) = p_0 + t d $

Point $p_0 = (p_{0x}, p_{0y})$ is any point on the line, and vector $d=(d_x, d_y)$ is the direction vector of the line.

The normal vector to the line pointing to its left is given by a rotation of $+90^\circ$ anti-clockwise of vector $d$, hence, $n = (-dy, dx)$.  Now point $c = (c_x, c_y) $ will be the left of the line if $(c - p_0) \cdot n$ is positive, i.e. if

$ (c_x - p_{0x} ) (-d_y) + (c_y - p_{0y}) (d_x) \gt 0 $